# Singleton use in different thread

Tags: java, android

I have a remote service and an, object (singleton). When I call the singleton class from UI thread and remote service I get 2 objects. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please post the code of the supposedly singleton class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a remote service then you have 2 completely separate processes. Each process has its own virtual machine. Therefore, your **singleton** class is instantiated once in **each** process.

If you really need a single then think about whether you really need a remote service. If you can implement your remote service as a local service then that will solve your problem.

If, on the other hand, you really need a single instance that is shared across the 2 separate processes, then you will need to instantiate the singleton **only** in the remote services process and access it via remote calls from the UI process.